# How does Google Maps represent an area as a point?

Tags: google-maps, geometry

Google Maps does an excellent job of using polygons to represent areas wherever possible, particularly [from the search bar](https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+Jersey/@40.1376066,-75.8522969,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c0fb959e00409f:0x2cd27b07f83f6d8d):

[image: nj1]

But in some cases (navigation) a point geometry is required, no matter how [vague or large-scale the area being searched](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Philadelphia,+PA/New+Jersey/@40.05806,-74.4070045,1138m/am=t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c6b7d8d4b54beb:0x89f514d88c3e58c1!2m2!1d-75.1652215!2d39.9525839!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c0fb959e00409f:0x2cd27b07f83f6d8d!2m2!1d-74.4056612!2d40.0583238), and this can result in some funny-at-best, completely-wrong-at-worst locations:

[image: nj2]

There are two ways that I know of that are widely used to generalize a polygon to a point:

1. Calculate the geometric centroid (there are various ways to do this but they'll all produce similar results)
2. Choose an point of administrative importance (i.e. navigating to "New York, NY" takes you to city hall)

In some cases Google appears to do neither of these things, and I can't figure out how the point was chosen. Specifically, [navigating to "Vermont" directs you to a field on the outskirts of a village in the Northern part of the state, far from any examples of 1. or 2. above.](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Philadelphia,+PA/Vermont/@44.558397,-72.5804104,969m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c6b7d8d4b54beb:0x89f514d88c3e58c1!2m2!1d-75.1652215!2d39.9525839!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cb4dc6c48daceff:0x264d897436546bb4!2m2!1d-72.5778415!2d44.5588028!5i1)

What other method could Google be using in cases like this?

Comment: Looks like it is where the name of the state appears on map.

Comment: @geocodezip The map label is placed on the area-represented-as-a-point, not the other way around. And that's not the case in Vermont anyway - the label is placed South of the destination point.

Comment: we are not google, how do you expect to get an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received information from side channels that this is a quirk of Google's geographic features algorithm. Many thanks for the suggestions, but this one appears to be less of a mysterious puzzle and more of a transient bug.